# holomorphic function, Cauchy Riemann equation

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

How can I show that the following functions are holomorphic on their domain of definition and that they satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equation?

1) $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{1}{z+1}$

2) $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{e^z}{z}$

I was trying to calculate $f(z) = (x+ iy +1)^{-1}$ and to split it into real and imaginary part to check the Cauchy Riemann equations, but I do not see how to go further. And how can I show that these functions are also holomorphic?

Answer (score 1):

If the satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations they are holomorphic.

For the first, $f(x,y)=1/(x+iy+1)=1/((x+1)+iy)\cdot((x+1)-iy)/((x+1)-iy)=1/((x+1)^2+y^2)((x+1)-iy)=u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$, where $u(x,y)=1/((x+1)^2+y^2)(x+1)$ and $v(x,y)=-1/((x+1)^2+y^2)y$.

Now you can check the C-R equations.

Comment: Thank you very much! And what happens if they do not satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equation everywhere? If there are some points where the Cauchy Riemann equation is not fulfilled, would this imply that the function is complex differentiable in the other points (where C.-R. equations hold)?

Comment: Being holomorphic is equivalent to satisfying the C-R equations (at a point).